# gridview subtotal using jquery in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview

happy new year to all,

i am having a problem in counting subtotal in a gridview in asp.net

the gridview contains details like

```
sl .no item reading  result
1 A [userentry] 
2  [userentry]
3  [userentry] [labeltodispresult]
1 B [userentry]
2  [userentry]
3  [userentry] [labeltodispresult]
```

i need to calculate the sum of the user entry for each item and display into the resultant lable.

let me tell you what i have achived, 
i am facing no problem at all in the gridview part.
when ever the user entry is made the value in the result lable should be updated,
i am binding a javascript function to the userentry textbox in rowdatabound event in code behind.
in the javascript i am able to roll over all the rows of table using jquery, and calculate the value.
here is the catch,
the labletodispresult should be for that item group only,
i.e. i need to get the sum of userentry for A -1,A-2, A-3 rows and seperately for B-1,B-2,B-3 rows,
the i am using a class for the userentry textbox, 
and using this

```
<asp:gridview id="gv1" runat="server">
<columns>

<ItemTemplate headertext="sl.no">

<asp:label id="lblslno" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("slno")%>' />

</ItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate headertext="Item">
<asp:label id="lblItem" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Item")%>' />

</ItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate headertext="readings">
<asp:TextBox id="txtReadings" runat="server" class="readings" />

</ItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate headertext="result">
<asp:label id="lblresult" runat="server"  />

</ItemTemplate>

</columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

jquery part:

```
function calculate(){
$('.readings').each(function(){

sumval +=parseFloat($(this).val());

});
}
```

this gives me all the textboxes sum value, but i need the values based on the Item group.
i am at a fix 
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one thing you can try. 
Set the class of your textbox = your item i.e.

CssClass='<%# Eval("Item")%>'

That is one way to differentiate your textboxes based on item. Then get your textbox based on that class.

Comment: based on the pointer provided by gbs i did a lot of manipulation to achieve my target, thanks bro. up one point for the sole person to take time to comment on my question.